# Fast access to object items of a private array or arraylist in the superclass

Tags: java, performance, inheritance, encapsulation

I store objects in an `BaseType` array of the superclass `BaseExplorer` which I would like to retrieve **as efficiently as possible** from the subclass `Explorer1` and use them as `Type1` objects there. (`Type1 extends BaseType`) All fields are private. `Explorer1` does not (need to) know how the objects are stored in `BaseExplorer`.

```
// data object classes
abstract class BaseType {}
class Type1 extends BaseType {}
class Type2 extends BaseType {}  // etc. (many TypeX classes)

// superclass storing the data objects with many methods manipulating them
abstract class BaseExplorer {
    private BaseType[] array; // Array of BaseType-Objects
    private List<BaseType> list; // alternatively a List or ArrayList

    public int getNumberOfObjects() {
        return array.length;   // or list.size() or whatever
    }
    public BaseType getObject(int i) {
        return array[i];    // or list.get(i) or whatever
    }
    // followed by many methods that are reused by all subsclasses Explorer1 ... ExplorerX
}

// one of many ExplorerX subclasses with their own TypeX data objects
class Explorer1 extends BaseExplorer {
    public Type1 getObject(int i) {
        return (Type1) super.getObject(i);
    }
    // followed by many methods that use the Type1 data objects
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Explorer1 explorer = new Explorer1();

    // followed by code constructing the Type1 objects in explorer which fill the array/list in Explorer

    // Virtually looping through the private array/list of Explorer1 and retrieving Type2 objects
    for (int i=0; i<explorer.getNumberOfObjects(); i++) {
        Type1 obj = explorer.getObject(i);
        // followed by code using obj as Type1 ...
    }
}
```

I have chosen this design, because the methods in `BaseExplorer` use the objects as `BaseType` objects (`BaseExplorer` does not know `Type1`) and the methods in `Explorer1` use them as `Type1` objects. Alternatively I have tried with Java Generics (`class BaseExplorer<T extends BaseType>` and `class Explorer1 extends BaseExplorer<Type1>`), but that ended up to complex in my real project which is a lot (!) more complex.)
The code is following the Java design principle that class fields should be private, with the benefit that `Explorer1` does not need to know how the Objects are stored in `BaseExplorer`. But this comes at the cost of speed, code simplicity and code beauty. What I dislike in this design is:

1. Using an integer loop variable instead of directly looping through
   the array:
   `for (Type1 obj : explorer.array) { ... }`
2. `explorer.getNumberOfObjects()` gets called in every repetition of the
   loop. (Ok, I could store it first, but that would make the code even
   heavier and uglier.)
3. `getObject(i)` is method call, which calls the method `super.getObject(i)`. So two more method calls that cost execution time. (I could avoid the subclasses' method, because its only function is the casting to Type1, but then I would have to do the casting in each and every use.)

Is there any "cheaper" or faster way to loop through all the objects and retrieve all `Type1` objects stored in the `BaseType` array one after the other? Or is there any completely different, better design?

Comment: this probably belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) than stackoverflow

Comment: all of your 3 points are *assumptions* of being slow, measure - I highly doubt that once JIT kicks in these method invocations are going to bite you performance wise

Comment: You cannot use enhanced for loop on primitive array `private BaseType[] array` because enhanced for loop uses Iterator.[Java Doc](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes) But if you want to use Iterator why not to pass a reference of ArrayList as it is already Iterable?On the other hand if you want to use primitive array the indexing is the way to go.

Comment: You can use generics, then you don't have to explicitly cast the objects

Comment: @Eugene: You are right, the JIT does a good job. I made a few speed tests which run the empty loops a few times up to a few million times, comparing indirect access (like in my code) with direct access to the array. The indirect acces takes 5 times longer, but this factor goes down to 1.3 when executed severyl million times. When I make the numberOfObjects a volatile field, it really slows down to a factor of 10, which shows nicely how the JIT works.

Comment: that is btw a general rule per-se, you have to measure and prove that something is slow before jumping in conclusions. about your examples `volatile` implies barriers, so this is pretty much expected. about methods dispatching you should read about method dispatching here https://shipilev.net/blog/2015/black-magic-method-dispatch/

Comment: @Debanjan: As I wrote I tried generics already, but the complexity gets too high, because I have not only one but many BaseTypes, with (unfortunately) many interdependencies.

Comment: @Eugene: I did all measurement BEFORE I posted this here. No jumping into conclusions, hard facts!

Comment: @AlexanderFrolov You're wrong, enhanced for loop on primitive array does work, it's simply implemented without iterators.